# Pandas netting values across rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Col1    Col2    H1  H2  H3
A       up      19  19  10
A       down        6   11
B       up          13  17
B       down    15  13  11
C       up      13  15  16
```

I want to get the following from above:

```
Col1    Col2    H1  H2  H3
A       up      19  13  
A       down            1
B       up              6
B       down    15      
C       up      13  15  16
```

Where for each `Col1, H1, H2, H3` type `Col2` values have been netted for `up` and `down`.

E.g. for

```
A       up      19  19  10
A       down        6   11
```

Net is

```
A       up      19  13  
A       down            1
```

Obtained by `19-0`, `19-6`, `11-10`

The number of rows and columns are very large so I am trying not to hard code their values or loop it. Is there a pandas ways of doing this ?

Comment: There is a pandas way for everything (hoho). Joke aside, you mention you are trying not to hard code a loop. What did you try then? Showing effort for a more "complicated"/elaborate question helps us understand we are not doing the work for you and you are actually looking for help. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try of taking difference of each grouped columns and reverse the sequence if there is any negative valu in column

```
df.groupby('Col1')['H1','H2','H3'].apply(lambda x:x.diff().fillna(0).transform(lambda x: list(reversed(x.tolist())) if any(x<0) else x) if len(x)>1 else x).abs()
```

Out:

```
    H1        H2    H3
0   19.0    13.0     0.0
1   0.0      0.0     1.0
2   0.0      0.0     6.0
3   15.0     0.0     0.0
4   13.0    15.0    16.0
```

I have tried to use reversing pandas list without reversed function, I dont know why it didnt work.

```
df.groupby('Col1')['H1','H2','H3'].apply(lambda x:x.diff().fillna(0).transform(lambda x: x[::-1] if any(x<0) else x) if len(x)>1 else x).abs()
```